# Operator as a vector field?!

Tags: vector-fields, parametrization

I am given the following vector field in spherical coordinates:

**v**=∂/∂t+∂/∂r

I am then asked to provide a parametrization (y^α)(μ) (α is a vector component, not an exponent) for the curves to which **v** is tangent.

I don't even understand how an operator be a vector field, let alone solve this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), review the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question to provide your motivation/attempts. Also, in vector calculus, the curl is a vector operator that describes the infinitesimal circulation of a vector field in three-dimensional Euclidean space,[via Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics))

Comment: What's _your_ definition of a vector field, then? Tell us what it is, and we'll see if we can't find a translation between them. Also, what's $t$? That's not common notation for a spherical coordinate.

Comment: It actually says spherical polar coordinates (t,r,θ,φ). t must correspond to z.

Comment: Well, I'm a physics student, so I'm used to vector fields being vector functions (that yield a vector at a point on the coordinate system). This is the first time I see an operator labeled as a vector field. This question is in an introductory course to differential geometry.

Comment: If we focus just on a single point, can you think of a sensible way to make one of your vectors into some form of derivative?

Comment: If it was eg **v** =∂/∂t **t** +∂/∂r **r** I would get it but with the form above it just doesn't look like a vector to me...